# How refactorable are AWS CDK applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code

I'm exploring how refactorable CDK applications are. Suppose I defined a custom construct (a stack) to create an EKS cluster. Let's call it `EksStack`. Ideally, I'd create the role to be associated with the cluster and the EKS cluster itself, as described by the following snippet (I'm using Scala instead of Java, so the snippets are going to be in Scala syntax):

```
class EksStack (scope: Construct, id: String, props: StackProps) extends Stack(scope, id, props) {
    private val role = new Role(this, "eks-role", RoleProps.builder()
        .description(...)
        .managedPolicies(...)
        .assumedBy(...)
        .build()
    )

    private val cluster = new Cluster(this, "eks-cluster", ClusterProps.builder()
        .version(...)
        .role(role)
        .defaultCapacityType(DefaultCapacityType.EC2)
        .build()
    )
}
```

When I synthetize the application, I can see that the generated template contains the definition of the VPC, together with the Elastic IPs, NATs, Internet Gateways, and so on.

Now suppose that I want to refactor `EksStack` and have a different stack, say `VpcStack`, explicitly create the VPC:

```
class VpcStack (scope: Construct, id: String, props: StackProps) extends Stack(scope, id, props) {
    val vpc = new Vpc(this, VpcId, VpcProps.builder()
      .cidr(...)
      .enableDnsSupport(true)
      .enableDnsHostnames(true)
      .maxAzs(...)
      .build()
    )
}
```

Ideally, the cluster in `EksStack` would just be using the reference to the VPC created by `VpcStack`, something like (note the new call to `vpc()` in the builder of cluster):

```
class EksStack (scope: Construct, id: String, props: StackProps, vpc: IVpc) extends Stack(scope, id, props) {
    private val role = new Role(this, "eks-role", RoleProps.builder()
        .description(...)
        .managedPolicies(...)
        .assumedBy(...)
        .build()
    )

    private val cluster = new Cluster(this, "eks-cluster", ClusterProps.builder()
        .version(...)
        .role(role)
        .vpc(vpc)
        .defaultCapacityType(DefaultCapacityType.EC2)
        .build()
    )
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, as CloudFormation would delete the VPC created by `EksStack` in favor of the one created by `VpcStack`. I read here and there and tried to add a retain policy in `EksStack` and to override the logical ID of the VPC in `VpcStack`, using the ID I originally saw in the CloudFormation template for `EksStack`:

```
val cfnVpc = cluster.getVpc.getNode.getDefaultChild.asInstanceOf[CfnVPC]
cfnVpc.applyRemovalPolicy(RemovalPolicy.RETAIN)
```

and

```
val cfnVpc = vpc.getNode.getDefaultChild.asInstanceOf[CfnVPC]
cfnVpc.overrideLogicalId("LogicalID")
```

and then retried the `diff`. Again, it seems that the VPC is deleted and re-created.

Now, I saw that it is possible to migrate CloudFormation resources (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/refactor-stacks.html) using the "Import resources into stack" action. My question is: can I move the creation of a resource from a stack to another in CDK without re-creating it?

EDIT:
To elaborate a bit on my problem, when I define the VPC in `VpcStack`, I'd like CDK to *think* that the resource was created by `VpcStack` instead ok `EksStack`. Something like *moving* the definition of it from one stack to another without having CloudFormation delete the original one to re-create it. In my use case, I'd have a stack define a create initially (either explicitly or implicitly, such as my VPC), but then, after I while, I might want to refactor my application, moving the creation of that resource in a dedicated stack. I'm trying to understand if this *moving* always leads to the resource being re-created of if there's any way to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem, but if you are trying to reference an existing resource you can use a context query. (e.g. `Vpc.fromLookup`).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/context.html

Additionally, if you would like to use the Vpc created from VpcStack inside of EksStack you can output the vpc id from the VpcStack and use the context query in the eks stack that way.

this is C# code but the principal is the same.

```
var myVpc = new Vpc(...);


new CfnOutput(this, "MyVpcIdOutput", new CfnOutputProps()
{
    ExportName = "VpcIdOutput",
    Value = myVpc.VpcId
}
```

and then when you create the EksStack you can import the vpc id that you previously exported.

```
new EksStack(this, "MyCoolStack", new EksStackProps()
{
    MyVpcId = Fn.ImportValue("VpcIdOutput")
}
```

where EksStackProps is

```
public class EksStackProps 
{
    public string MyVpcId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I jotted down a little additional explanationin the question. If I understood well, the only thing I can do is reference the existing VPC from another stack. Hence, the VPC would still "belong" to EksStack (i.e. I'll see it in the Output tab in CloudFormation, for example). The more I think about it the more it makes sense, anyway. May I ask you what's the behavior of the look-up if the VPC doesn't happen to exist? I investigated this for the Roles, and it seems the look-up never returns null if the resource doesn't exist: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9941

Comment: Oh okay I think I get it. You can't move the 'creation' itself to another stack. But in any case, you don't need to delete an existing vpc. You can change your EksStack to just use Vpc.fromLookup. Your EksStack can only do one of two things. Create a new VPC or use an existing one. It becomes your decision as the developer if you want the EksStack to be responsible for this or if you want to do it another way.

Comment: To answer your other question, it will throw an exception during synth if it cant find the vpc in the target region/account.

Answer (score 4):

I think when it comes to refactorability when CDK and CloudFormation in general, especially multi stack configurations, there are a few principles to keep in mind.

1. The entire app should be able to be completely deleted and recreated.  All data management is handled in the app, there is no manual processes that need to occur.
2. Don't always rely on auto interstack dependency management using Stack exports.  I like to classify CloudFormation dependencies into two categories: Hard and soft.  Hard dependencies means that you cannot delete the resource because the things using it will prevent it from happening.  Soft dependencies are the opposite, the resource could be deleted and recreated without issue even though something else is using it.  Hard dependency examples: VPC, Subnets.  Soft dependency examples: Topic/Queue/Role.
3. You'll have a better time passing stack soft dependencies as Stack parameters of SSM Parameter type because you'll be able to update the stack providing the dependencies independent of those using it.  Whereas you get into a deadlock when using default stack export method.  You can't delete the resources because something else is importing it. So you end up having to do annoying things to make it work like deploying once with it duplicated then deploying again deleting the old stuff.  It requires a little extra work to use SSM Parameters without causing stack exports but it is worth it long term for soft dependencies.
4. For hard dependencies, I disagree with using a lookup because you really do want to prevent deletion if something is using it bc you'll end up with a DELETE_FAILED stack and that is a terrible place to end up.  So for things like VPC/Subnets, I think it's really important to actually use stack export/import technique and if you do need to recreate your VPC because of a change, if you followed principle 1, you just need to do a CDK destroy then deploy and all will be good because you built your CDK app to be fully recreatable.
5. When it comes to recreatability with data, CustomResources are your friend.

Comment: Those principles really shed a light on how AWS CF works, thanks! Based on that, I figure the way to go in my use case is to simply pass references to the CDK objects created by one stack to other stacks. As long as the stacks are in the same region, this should be synthesizes AWS CloudFormation `exports` in the producing stack and an `Fn::ImportValue` in the consuming stack.